# Android. How to make clickable html string?

Tags: android, html, android-view, url-scheme, android-spannable

I have html string. I need to show my it in my TextView. Here is my code:

```
tvText.setText(Html.fromHtml(htmlString));
```

Html string contains some text, but may also contains links. I need to detect if a string contains a link, make part of that string clickable.

I can do a search for links in a string myself and then use SpannableString and ClickableSpan.

But perhaps there is some way to set a click in html and then the mobile application will be able to react for some reason and make part of the string clickable.

Please help me.

UPD: I can request an html string in any form, so I need to understand what it should be in order to process a click in a mobile application without any search for links in string.

Comment: What does the String look like? (Mainly the link part)

Comment: @TheLibrarian, I can request a String in any form, I just need to know in which one so that I can associate a click with a mobile application. Unfortunately I am very weak in html

Answer (score 1):

Try to wrap your links in html `<a>` tags and set movement method to your textView like this:

```
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml("This is a <a href=\"https://google.com/\">link</a>"));
textView.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: thank you for answer, but what if the String contains, in addition to the link, also plain text, which should not be clickable? Then the whole text will be clickable, right?

Comment: Only the link is clickable here @testivanivan

Comment: And if the ability to perform custom click processing?

Comment: Use `ClickableSpan` for custom click processing

Comment: That is, for a custom click, I will have to independently find links in the String and their indices in order to set the click by index with ClickableSpan ?